# How can i count the sequence of 1 or 0 in vector of 1 and 0 in R?

Tags: r, matrix, count, sequence

I need to create function that receive as argument a vector of 1, 0 and NA values. for example:

```
vec<-c(1, 0, 1, 0, NA, 0, 1, 0)
create_matrice <- function(vec){
   # ...
   return m # return matrice
}
```

This sequence represents the number of shots in a football match, 1: there was a goal, 0: there was no goal, NA: we do not know if there was a goal or not.

my function wants to calculate the number of sequence 00, 01, 10, and 11. if you have a NA in vector, you have to skip it as follows:
let us admit our vector is the one given with <-c (1, 0, 1, 0, NA, 0, 1, 0). Thus the new vector will be separated into 2 vector for: vec1 = 1 0 1 0 and the second vector vec2 = 0 1 0
So, my function must return a 2 * 2 dimension matrix,
for which :
1st line: the first shot is 1,
2nd line: the first shot is 0,
1st column: the second shot is 1,
2nd column: the second draw is 0.
  I initialize my matrix:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

ainsi au finale je doit retrouve: m[1,1] = count11, m[2,1] = count01, m[1,2] = count10, m[2,2] = count00

I tried to make it alone but i could not. can someone heps me please ?

Comment: Can you show how the matrix `m` would look for the given `vec` ?

Comment: Does `table(c(vec,NA),c(NA,vec))` what you want (albeit with row order reversed, and column order also reversed).

Comment: my final matrix for the vector input : return matrix(c(0,3,2,0), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

Comment: `table(c(NA,vec),c(vec,NA))` should work as suggested bu @Miff

Comment: Similar to @Miff: `table(head(vec, -1), tail(vec, -1))`

Comment: @Miff it works thanks!  thank you everyone !

Comment: @SharonS, you are encouraged to post an answer to your own question ...